# Javascript multiplication/division in one form

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript calculation where I need to multiply and divide several answers all in one form.

I got the initial multiplication to work for #1 and #2 (see below), but unfortunately I'm having issues with a code I wrote to divide two elements in the next section.

Basically, I need to divide Answer #2 by Answer #3.

Thanks.

```html
 1. <input type="text" name="f1" id="f1" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Multiply by 12:" onclick="calculate();" />
<br />
<br />
 2. <input type="text" name="res" id="res" /> <br />
 <br />
 3. <input type="text" name="f2" id="f2" /> <br />
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Divide answer 2 by answer 3:" onclick="calculate();" /><br /><br /> 4. <input type="text" name="res2" id="res2" /> <br />
 <br />
 



<script>
    function calculate() {
    var f1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f1').value);
    var res = f1 * 12;
    document.getElementById('res').value = res;
    
    function calculate() {
    var f2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f2').value);
    var res2 = res / f2;
    document.getElementById('res2').value = res2;
  }
}
</script>    

<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your function definitions.

1. Both of your functions are named `calculate`. You must give each function a unique name.
2. Your first `calculate` function actually contains the second one (there is a missing brace).

Do this:

```
function calculateMul() {
  var f1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f1').value);
  var res = f1 * 12;
  document.getElementById('res').value = res;
}

function calculateDiv() {
  var f2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f2').value);
  var res = parseInt(document.getElementById('res').value);
  var res2 = res / f2;
  document.getElementById('res2').value = res2;
}
```

... and call these functions in your `onClick` event handlers.

Comment: Thanks, I think that put me on the right track... Unfortunately, it's still not dividing the answers from lines #2 and #3...

Comment: I see that `calculateDiv` requires the value from the `res` field, so you'd have to grab that too. I've edited my answer accordingly.